# Sip: Prevent INVITE request information spoofing

Tags: sip

I have a service that sends identification information through SIP INVITE requests, such as a user's username in the FROM header field. I would like to know if these is anyone to prevent an attacker, who already has access to my server, to create their own INVITE and send it to another user pretending to be another user in the network. Thank you and have a great one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attacker doesn't need access to your server to send an INVITE request in your user's name. He can do that from anywhere in the network. This is where [authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-22) comes in. The recipient (UAS) can challenge the request, forcing the attacker to resend the request with authentication information, such as (hashed) passwords.

Of course this mechanism relies on the attacker not having the username/password combinations. This could prove a problem if he already has access to your server. But I think you might have bigger problems in that case.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you! If you do not mind me asking, do you know of how to do this with the Kamailio sip server? Or, should I create a separate question for that as well (sorry, I do not use stack overflow a lot)?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with Kamailio. I think you should use the [Auth module](https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/stable/modules/auth.html). If you have any questions related to that module (and can't find the answer on StackOverflow) you can always ask a new question.

Comment: Alright, and I am pretty sure that is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much for your help, I truly appreciate it; have a great one, :)!